# Get model's fully qualified name

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Is there a sexier way to get **App.User** from a string **'user'** than something like

```
 eval("App." + modelName.classify())
```

What about getting **App.User** from the content object in a controller?

Comment: Is the `'user'` string supposed to be a variable? If not, why can't you just use `App.User`?

Comment: Yeah, it's a variable. This is just an example of what the value might look like.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid using `eval()` by using bracket notation instead: `App[modelName.classify()]`